# how to remove date from datetime in Linq c#

Tags: c#, linq

i want to get only time from a datetime variable in linq query.
for eaxample if i have an array of datetime having values

```
["02/12/1970 14:52:06","14/06/2015 12:32:44"]
```

then how to extract minimum time from it so that i get output like

```
"12:32:44"
```

as if i take minimum these two it will give output
`"14:52:44"` instead of `"12:32:44"`
as the datepart of first value is smaller than the other.

i try this code:

```
time1 = table1.Min(x=>x.StartTime)
```

but it will give "14:52:06" as output

any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Be clear on where the data is coming from (e.g. is this Entity Framework?).

Comment: "00:00:00" is the minimum time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First extract Time from DateTime and then get Min value

```
var dates = new List<DateTime>
{
    new DateTime(2020, 6, 9, 12, 35, 45),
    new DateTime(2020, 6, 10, 11, 35, 45)
};

var minTime = dates
    .Select(d => d.TimeOfDay)
    .Min();
```

### #Update

If you want to get DateTime object that has the smallest `time` part, then use this:

```
var dateWithMinTime = dates
    .OrderBy(d => d.TimeOfDay)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: cannot convert system.timespan to system.datetime

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
table1.Min(c => c.StartTime.TimeOfDay)
```

assuming `StarTime` is a `DateTime`.

Comment: cannot convert system.timespan to system.datetime